# Use of internal methods to load database records into a domain object

Tags: c#, oop

I have a Form object in my domain layer that contains multiple records (corresponds to a table row) in an hierarchical manner. These records have fields (columns of that table). The application user is allowed to update fields and add/remove records from the form. This public API of the form object kicks the validation rules of the form.

But how do I load database values into form object? As data access layer knows the domain layer, should I create internal methods in my domain objects? So that when the service layer (sitting on top of domain) ask the data access layer for a form object, the data access layer can use those internal methods to create the required domain object.

```
public class DEForm
{
    public DEForm(FormNumber number){}

    public AddRecord(RecordNumber to, string type) { // do some validation here}

    internal AddExisting(Record record, RecordNumber to){}
}
```

Sorry, this might be a newbie question. I don't have much experience in designing applications. Let me know if the information is confusing, I will add more details.

Thanks.

Comment: if I understand what you are going for, you have a database already and want a way to get the data in and out via framework? I would look here [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Comment: Yes. we already have the data base and data access code written. We are trying to organize our code. our UI, Domain, BL, and DAL everything is very tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of patterns to accomplish what you are asking. I do not intend to comment on, or list them here, just to outline the pattern I normally use.

The bottom tier is the source repository for data. It could be a database, a web service, a WCF service, an Enterprise Service Bus, or whatever. It is where you get the data you need to populate the domain objects.

The next tier up consists of the data access layer and the domain objects. In my designs domain objects are stupid. They are simply data containers. The data access layer consists of Data Access Objects (DAO). These objects are responsible for querying the data source and populating the required domain objects with data. Each domain object has a DAO specific to it.

The DAOs each provide the methods Fetch, FetchList, Insert, InsertList, Update, UpdateList, Delete, and DeleteList. Internally the Fetch methods use a private method called Transform which takes a Record (from a DataReader when the data source is a database) as a parameter, and returns the appropriate domain object.

The next tier up is the Repository layer, this layer is responsible for using the DAOs to populate/persist compound objects (objects which contain data and child objects).

The next tier is the Business layer which has objects which apply business rules.

The next tier is the service layer. This layer makes data available to the Interface layer.

The Interface layer is the presentation (for UI based applications) or exposed interface (web service, WCF service, etc.).

I am in no way claiming this is the "Right" or "Best" pattern, just that it is the pattern that I use.

Comment: So the domain object have public getters and setters that can be used by both DAO/repository and business layer. But the business layer runs validations and UI layers knows that layer. Is that right?

Comment: Right, except that the UI layer only has direct access to the Service layer. The Service layer knows about the Business layer.

Comment: Thanks. it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain encapsulation, your design must prevent objects in your business layer from being created externally; that is, it should not be possible to `new` a `DEForm` from outside the BL. This is to guarantee that the rules of creation of your objects are enforced by the BL only. If you want your objects to be hydrated with data coming from the data access layer, expose a factory (e.g. `DEFormFactory`) that the data access layer (or a bridge class) invokes.

Or, you can use an ORM, such as Entity Framework.

Comment: But the factory has to be public then, right. And the factory will have to use the internal AddExisting method to hydrate. If I don't expose the internal AddExisting method, I will have to use reflection, right?

Comment: It is OK to expose the factory, as it is needed to create business objects and it still encapsulates the rules of instantiation; so, there is no need for using reflection.

Comment: I guess the reason I have this doubt is because the Data Access layer, Domain layer, and service layer are separate projects. And I was thinking only DAL and Domain should have access to AddExisting method. May be, I am trying to control too much.

Comment: Your intentions are correct: you should keep the projects separate. You then need a bridge assembly between the two. In our projects, we prefix the assembly with `.Runtime` as a naming convention.

Comment: so kind of data mapper layer/project?

Comment: Yes and no. Do not restrict your bridge to moving data. Its goal should be to orchestrate the calls to the methods (interface) of the different assemblies, whether they are to get and put data or execute operations.